# Data annotation for IFormFile so it only allows files with .png, .jpg or .jpeg extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC. I need a data annotation/custom data annotation for `IFormFile`, that check the file selected/uploaded is an Image, the extension of the image has to match `*.png`, `*.jpg` or `*.jpeg` . This is the view model

```cs
public class ProductViewModel 
{
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pick an Image")]
    //[CheckIfItsAnImage(ErrorMessage = "The file selected/uploaded is not an image")]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
public class AllowedExtensionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] _extensions;

    public AllowedExtensionsAttribute(string[] extensions)
    {
        _extensions = extensions;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var file = value as IFormFile;
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (!_extensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage()
    {
        return $"Your image's filetype is not valid.";
    }
}
```

put to your code

```cs
public class ProductViewModel 
{

    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pick an Image")]
    [AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" })]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Chameera is pretty close with his answer but unfortunately the built in `FileExtensions` `DataAnnotation` only works on strings and not on IFormFile. Here is the solution:

```
public class ProductViewModel 
{
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pick an Image")]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }

    [FileExtensions(Extensions = "jpg,jpeg")]
    public string FileName => File?.FileName;
}
```

Comment: The file-name property must NOT be private! And yes this works, tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Based on **`Do Nhu Vy`** answer. You can also implement the custom data validation in this way:

```
public class AllowedExtensionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] _extensions;

    public AllowedExtensionsAttribute(string[] extensions)
    {
        _extensions = extensions;
    }


    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is null)
            return true;

        var file = value as IFormFile;
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

        if (!_extensions.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

And then on your view model specify the Error Message:

```
public class ProductViewModel 
{
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pick an Image")]
    [FileExtensions("jpg,jpeg,png", ErrorMessage = "Your image's filetype is not valid.")]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```